# Add an image to Django admin header

Tags: django-templates, django-admin

How do I display an image in the header of Django's admin (I refer to the place on the top of the page with the yellow title "Django administration" with blue background)?

I've tried to so with the HTML tag of `<img>` with some absolute path (under the assumption that the server and the client are running on the same machine):

```
<img width="225" height="151" src="C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\media\img\admin\sunrise.png" alt="Sunrise here">
```

But the image isn't displayed (just the string "Sunrise here").